# Voltage to current converter

Tags: operational-amplifier, converter, darlington

In the circuit diagram, R11 is the DUT across which current needs to be measured. According to tests performed on the device, the output current is 1A for sinusoidal input of amplitude 10V and frequency 50Hz. When I am simulating this circuit using LTSpice, the output current is 400μA. The device also uses the offset null pins of OP07 which are not available in LTSpice Model. What is the problem? Also, how can I increase the output current (current through R11)? R6 is load and I have taken arbitrary value for it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The TIP122 isn't wired as you show: -

[image]

You have a push-pull stage formed by the two power transistors and base is on pin 1 - it looks you you are trying to use pin 2 as the base.

Ditto the TIP127.

Check the circuit again in case you have made other basic errors like this.

Comment: I have used the Spice model for TIP122 and  TIP127 (from http://robustdesignconcepts.com/files/pspice/libs/darlngtn.lib) which uses second pin as base, first for collector and third for emitter. The model has been generated accordingly.